# How to merge two pandas dataframes with repeated fields. e.g. customers and sales

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes: one for sales other for customers.

I need to create a third dataframe, but using merge doesn't work:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('sales.csv', sep=';')
df2 = pd.read_csv('cust.csv', sep=';')

df1.shape = (423413, 21)
df2.shape = (231286, 12)
```

of course, some customers made more than one purchase. But when I use merge, the dataframe is bigger than the sum of the two previous dataframes and it doesn't matter which method: inner, outer, right, left. Always give a value greater than the sum of the two

```
data_sum = df1.merge(df2, on='Id_Customer', how='left')
data_sum.shape = (745711, 32)
```

I've been trying to merge, join, concat and nothing works

Some customers made more than one purchase and customers who never purchased anything.
How could I create a new dataframe that looks up the sales table ID, finds the reference in the customers table, and presents the sales and customer data in this?

Comment: You should provide a concrete example (with the data as text)

Comment: Thank's, @Mozway . The dataframe shape values ​​are real, with accuracy.
I can put the result in each of the merge possibilities, if applicable

Answer (score 0):

The number might be the result of processing of the `DataFrame`s,   sales without a `customer_id` and vice versa, etc. As suggested in the comments it is difficult to say without data, but below an example demonstrating that the `merge` function works as expected.

```py
import pandas as pd

cust = pd.DataFrame({
    'adress': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'id': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
})

sales = pd.DataFrame({
    'nr': [10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 1],
    'id': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 10]
})

merge = pd.merge(cust, sales, how='outer')
print(merge)

merge2 = pd.merge(cust, sales, how='inner')
print(merge2)

merge3 = pd.merge(cust, sales, how='left')
print(merge3)

merge4 = pd.merge(cust, sales, how='right')
print(merge4)
```

Comment: Exactly Marcel, but the results end up being more rows than the original sales dataframe (which is not possible), The last dataframe would be to put the column corresponding to the customers and fill it with the rows corresponding to the customer data.